# Django Authentication Hardcoding Users

Tags: django, authentication

I have a django project with two apps (app and authenticate) that I got from a template. I developped my "app" app and it works fine. Now I want to add logins to limit access to certain pages of the app.

I looked accross the Internet and they use

```
user = User.objects.create_user('myusername', 'myemail@crazymail.com', 'mypassword')
```

to create a user. I tried that (and tried logging in with the username and password but it doesn't work. I probably put the code in a wrong area (I put it in authentication/models.py). I would really like this to work but I can't seem to figure out why the user isn't created.

Answer (score -2):

there is no method create_user(). You must write User.objects.create('myusername', 'myemail@crazymail.com', 'mypassword')

Comment: sorry ) I was too fast ))  User.objects.create_user(username = 'myusername', email =  'myemail@crazymail.com', password =  'mypassword').

Comment: still nothing x) Otherwise, I think I could use the python manage.py createsuperuser and use the admin page to create users. But the VSCode Terminal doesn't like commands, whenever I type something like that I get an error so I don't know what to do

Comment: @VitAmin there _is_ a method `create_user` in the user models manager, please _research_ a bit before giving answers if you don't know about it.